# Unexpected Python KeyError python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, keyerror

I have loaded a CSV file

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from scipy.stats import norm
```

This data will then be loaded

```
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
```

Print data

```
print(data.columns)
```

output :Index(['age;SEX;bmi;bp;S1;S2;S3;S4;S5;S6;Y'], dtype='object')

Get column 'age', 'bmi', and 'bp'

```
age_data = data ['age'].values
bmi_data = data ['bmi'].values
bp_data = data ['bp'].values
```

and the error:

```
KeyError: 'age'
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong? This error is generated when you try to grab data from a column which doesn't match the name, or if the column doesn't have that header namne. However, it does.

Error Information:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'age'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-92eb9b4ecfe3> in <cell line: 2>()
      1 # Mendapatkan kolom 'age', 'bmi', dan 'bp'
----> 2 age_data = data ['age'].values
      3 bmi_data = data ['bmi'].values
      4 bp_data = data ['bp'].values
      5 # Menghitung jumlah kemunculan setiap jenis kelamin

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   3805             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   3806                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 3807             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   3808             if is_integer(indexer):
   3809                 indexer = [indexer]

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3802                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3803             except KeyError as err:
-> 3804                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   3805             except TypeError:
   3806                 # If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error will raise

KeyError: 'age'
```

Answer (score 1):

You table is delimited with semicolons (`;`), but you used the default value for `sep` parameter in `read_csv` (a comma `,`)

Try: `pandas.read_csv(filename, sep=“;”)`

Comment: Thank you for answering my question, I have tried it but still have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

IF you look at the output when you print the data, you get:

```
output :Index(['age;SEX;bmi;bp;S1;S2;S3;S4;S5;S6;Y'], dtype='object')
```

where the index is the entire first line as one blob. if you print out the whole dataframe:

```
print(data)
```

You should see that everything is in the first column.  You'll need to separate by semi-colon ';' instead of comma, as the other commenter noted.

Comment: thank you for answering my question I have checked the program, the output has been separated by a ;